# Is this a right Strategy implementation

Tags: c#, strategy-pattern

I have tried to implement the Head First Duck problem with Startegy. I am trying to implement the Decoy Duck, which intially don't have the facility to Quack or Fly is implemented by calling a a default constructor( I know this duck don't have the ability to Fly or Quack). All other Ducks are intitialized by calling the overriden consturctor. In the book a duck with no Fly is implemented with a class FlyNoFly which implements the IFly interface.

For my solution, i am not using this class. Instead, i am checking in the base duck class the Fly propery whether a valid instance is passed for it or not (by if(Fly != null) . if the Fly has a valid reference, then only i am invloking the fly method on that. Else i am throwing a default message.

I want to know whether my implementation is violating any design principle / Whether this is a valid implementation.

Thanks
TutuMon

```
public abstract class Duck
{
    public IFlyable Fly { get; set; }
    public IQuackable Quack { get; set; }
    public void PerformQuack()
    {
        //Is this checking valid as per OO?
        if (Quack != null)
            Quack.Quack();
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Quack Operation Not supported");
    }

    public void PerformFly()
    {
         //Is this checking valid as per OO?
         if (Fly != null)
             Fly.Fly();
         else
             Console.WriteLine("Fly Operation not supported");
    }

    public abstract void Swim();
}

public class MallardDuck : Duck
{
    public MallardDuck()
    {
    }

    public MallardDuck(IFlyable fly, IQuackable quack)
    {
        Fly = fly;
        Quack = quack;
    }

    public override void Swim()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mallard Duck is Swimming");
    }
}


//No Fly and Quack behaviour by default
public class DecoyDuck : Duck
{
     public DecoyDuck()
     {
     }

     public DecoyDuck(IFlyable fly, IQuackable quack)
     {
         Fly = fly;
         Quack = quack;
     }

     public override void Swim()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("DecoyDuck Duck is Swimming");
     }
}

public interface IFlyable
{
     void Fly();
}

public class FlyWithWings : IFlyable
{
     public void Fly()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You are flying with wings");
     }
}

public class RocketFly : IFlyable
{
    public void Fly()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Rocket Powered Fly");
    }
}

public interface IQuackable
{
    void Quack();
}

public class RealQUack :IQuackable
{
   public void Quack()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("This is Real Quack");
   }
}

public class PowerQuack : IQuackable
{
    public void Quack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Powerful Quacking ");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Duck mallard = new MallardDuck
        {Fly=new FlyWithWings(),Quack=new RealQUack()}
        mallard.PerformQuack();
        mallard.PerformFly();

        // He can't Quack or Fly by default
        // So i am calling the default constructor.
        Duck decoy = new DecoyDuck();
        decoy.PerformQuack();
        decoy.PerformFly();

        // Adding behaviours on the fly

        decoy.Fly = new RocketFly();
        decoy.Quack = new PowerQuack();

        decoy.PerformQuack();
        decoy.PerformFly();   
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the StackExchange site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is better suited to this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not the correct implementation.

The Strategy pattern is used to avoid the use of `if (..)` in Object Oriented Code. If you would use the FlyNoFly class you would avoid the `if ( null )` check and you can use the same constructor for all Duck objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not worried about the constructors here and we can remove all the constructors from the code too.